# Informatica : Error in getting DataEntry: Read time out

Tags: java, google-analytics, informatica-powercenter

I have created a source based Informatica Connector for Google analytics which connects to Google Analytics and fetches data into Informatica. Have used Informatica JAVA API and Google Analytics JAVA API to develope the connector. While running the mapping I'm getting the error:

> [ERROR] com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.SDKException: Error in getting DataEntry : Read time out

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a generic error we might hit during the runtime of the task intermittently. This needs to be captured to understand the root cause. We can update the attached jars in lower environments to debug the issue and understand the root cause.

Jars need to be updated in the agent directory:
\Informatica Cloud Secure Agent\downloads\package-GoogleAnalytics.x\package\googleanalytics\cci\plugins
com.infa.adapter.googleanalytics.messages.runtime-10.2.200.17.48-SNAPSHOT.jar
com.infa.adapter.googleanalytics.runtime.adapter-10.2.200.17.48-SNAPSHOT.jar

The above version of the jar might change, please rename accordingly with the current version in your agent and rename the following jars.
jars.zip (1).txt